# How do I predict an address given a salt in python?

Tags: pallet-contracts, py-substrate-interface

I have python code that does deploy a few ink! contracts that depend on each other. In order to do this in a batch call, I want to predict the contract address given the salt.

How would I do this, assuming I have the DefaultAddressGenerator:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/address.rs#L55C41-L55C64

Question is basically to port this to python.